# Updating a table with a composite key not working correctly

Tags: mysql, primary-key, composite-primary-key, on-duplicate-key

I have the following table:
[image]

As you can see, date and bed form a composite primary key.

I am trying to run this query:

```
INSERT INTO days (date, operating_time, bed) VALUES ('2016-11-07', 6.55, 1) ON duplicate key update operating_time=VALUES(operating_time);
```

The problem is that it seems to update based *only* on the date column. So for example, running the above query for a bed value of 1, and then re-running it but with a bed value of 2 will actually update the *original* record (the one where bed = 1)

How can I make the `ON DUPLICATE KEY` statement check both the date and bed columns?

Edit

Here is the create statement for the table:

```
CREATE TABLE `days` (
  `date` date NOT NULL,
  `operating_time` float DEFAULT '0',
  `bed` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`date`,`bed`),
  UNIQUE KEY `date_UNIQUE` (`date`),
  KEY `bed_idx` (`bed`),
  KEY `date` (`date`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: are you sure this didn't work?

Comment: @barudo I just tried it again on a completely blank table with the exact structure as above. It did not work.

Comment: Cannot reproduce.  Works as expected for me.

Comment: its because of the UNIQUE key on date... so mysql cannot add another row (they have the same date). If you'll try to have the same bed and date (but different operating time), it will update the operating time.

Comment: yes, mine failed as soon as I added that (actually it would not let me add the UNIQUE index to the table with data in it)

Comment: I changed the unique key to both the date and bed columns and it worked.... I didn't know a composite key had to be UNIQUE and not primary... Curious...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After posting the create statement for the table, it because evident that the UNIQUE key was composed of only the date column. After adding the bed column, it worked as expected. I will need to read up on the different types of keys and why specifically the UNIQUE key must contain both columns used in the composite key.

Answer (score 2):

The table `days` has a `UNIQUE` index on date so if you do an `INSERT` with a same date but different `bed`, it won't be inserted because of the UNIQUE (else it fails the unique index).

If you try inserting with the same `bed` and `date` (but different `operating_time`), it will make an UPDATE.